# Rounding-up TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I gotta be missing something obvious.

```
select CEILING(85/30) = 2

85/30 = 2.83333
```

I want the value to be 3.

Shouldn't the CEILING function round up for me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT CEILING(85.0/30)
```

And for comparison

```
SELECT 85.0 / 30, 85 / 30
```

The first example uses floats, the second uses ints, so the result is rounded before the ceiling function is hit. What you do is

```
SELECT CEILING(2)
```

Rather than

```
SELECT CEILING(2.833333)
```

Answer (score 3):

Change it for :

```
select CEILING(85/30.0)
```

INT / INT yields an INT, so 85/30 rounds it down (FLOOR).

Answer (score 1):

Use some typed-parameters, and you won't have to worry so much about how you enter the data.  Here's a sam

```
DECLARE @int_num integer
DECLARE @int_dem integer
DECLARE @dec_num decimal(18,0)
DECLARE @dec_dem decimal(18,0)

SET @int_num = 85
SET @int_dem = 30
SET @dec_num = 85
SET @dec_dem = 30

SELECT CEILING(@int_num / @int_dem) AS int_div, CEILING(@dec_num / @dec_dem) AS dec_div

int_div   |   dec_div
----------------------
2         |   3
```