# sql rounding up to a multiple of 5?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello i was wondering is there a way to round up to a multiple of 5 in SQL?

For example this only rounds up to ten if i set @Order = 8 or 9 but when it's 7 or 6 it rounds down to 5, i need it to round up to 10 when it's 6 or 7.

```
declare @Order int

set @Order = 7

select round(cast(@Order as float)/cast(5 as float),0)*5
```

I need

- `@Order = 1,2,3,4` to round up to 5
- `@Order = 6,7,8,9` to round up to 10
- `@Order = 11,12,13,14` to round up to 15

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098090/rounding-up-tsql

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the CEILING function

```
SELECT CEILING(@Order / 5.0) * 5
```

Comment: Doesn't work. e.g `select CEILING(2 / 5) * 5` produces `0` while it needs to produce `5`

Comment: You need to make the divisor `Real` to make this work. This `SELECT CEILING(@Order / 5.) * 5` works - with added dot.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT CEILING(@Order / 5.0) * 5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use built-in functions and avoid using `CASE` statements, have a look at this one:

```
select @Order, 5 * ((@Order+4) / 5)
```

For first 20 number result will look like:

```
number      rounded
----------- -----------
1           5
2           5
3           5
4           5
5           5
6           10
7           10
8           10
9           10
10          10
11          15
12          15
13          15
14          15
15          15
16          20
17          20
18          20
19          20
20          20
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another approach to the same problem.

```
declare @num as int
set @num = 12

select @num + case when @num%5=0 then 0 else 5-(@num%5) end
```